# Convert to decimal problem error reading comma

Tags: c#, .net

I'm doing a calculation to know a value. The fact is that when I take the value of an excel which value is 3.666 (and my string reads it as 3.666) the visual reads it as 3666 when I convert it to decimal since the point in excel is not for decimals. How can I tell him that's a comma?

```
List<MappedCsv> LFridays = ValorAperturaEnBolsa();
Decimal ValorApertura;
Decimal nAccionesDia;
Decimal nAccionesTotal = 0;

foreach(MappedCsv MC in LFridays)
{
    ValorApertura = Convert.ToDecimal(MC.Apertura);
    nAccionesDia = 49 / ValorApertura;
    nAccionesDia = Math.Round(nAccionesDia, 3);
    nAccionesTotal += nAccionesDia;
}
```

Comment: Just pass the correct CultureInfo to [Convert.ToDecimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todecimal?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Convert_ToDecimal_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_).

Comment: @KlausGütter and how can I do that?

Comment: Is the value of MC.Apertura returning a string like "3.666"?

Comment: you can also change excel settings to make point as decimal sperator

Comment: @Zingers yes, the string value is "3.666"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the string always contains a '.' as decimal separator, convert it using

```
ValorApertura = Convert.ToDecimal(MC.Apertura, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```